# I want to fill a column based on another columns

Tags: excel, vba, fill

I want a VBA function that fills column c based on the following criteria. 
Note: I cannot use a formula because column c already has values.

IF B is blank then C equals -D

I want this to work for a range of a 1000 rows

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This site is not a code writing service. We are a community that helps professionals with specific issues with the projects they are working on. In order to receive help, please provide the code you have written so far, describe why it doesn't do what you want it to do, and what you want it to do. Please  include any error messages, or specific information regarding the issue. Have a look at the [tour] and [help] page before editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Adjust to your needs.

```
Sub fill()

For x = 1 To 1000
If Range("B" & x).Value = "" Then Range("C" & x).Value = Range("D" & x).Value * -1
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Worked perfectly my code only worked for 1 row i didn't know how to put it to work for a 1000 rows.

Comment: You're welcome! please mark as answered.